# Reload SharedPreferences on resume? (or how to refresh/reload activity)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onresume

How can I reload SharedPreferences when I resume from one activity to another? If I resume, it is possible that user has changed the settings. Is it possible to reload SharedPreferences or do I need to refresh/reload activity. And if, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in how you get and set `SharedPreferences` normally and from doing so in `onResume`.  What you will need to do in addition to getting the most recent preferences, is update any objects you have in the `Activity` that use preference values.  This will ensure your `Activity` is working with the most recent values.

A simple example:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        getPrefs();

    //...Now update your objects with preference values         
}

private void getPrefs() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String myPref = prefs.getString("myPref", "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You're answered solved my problem. I accidentally called getDefaultSharedPreferences onCreate rather than onStart. Thank you.

Comment: In your example, is `getPrefs()` suppose to return anything?

Comment: `super.onResume()` MUST be called at last line of `onResume()` method. http://cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture05/lecture05.html