# Dismiss splash activity on resume

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle

I have two activities in my application. SplashActivity and MainActivity. Here is their manifest definition.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I want to finish SplashActivity after it shown , as you see it is defined as noHistor and calling MainActivity after 10 seconds so ;

```
       Intent a = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
       a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(a);
       finish();
```

When i take application to background and trying to resume , it is not resuming from MainActivity , it shows SplashActivity again.. how can i prevent this ? is it a known bug ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show the code of both activities if its not too long. It will help

Comment: they are really too long, but as a summary , i am doing login works in splash activity and when login success , i am going MainActivity. So i want to dismiss splashActivity onResume from background. There are some questions about this topic but no solution. You can see another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682439/how-to-show-splash-screen-only-when-the-app-starts-fresh

Comment: The answer on that thread seems helpful. You can keep a boolean variable in SharedPreference. If its first time, keep it true and in onResume, just check the sharedPreference variable and accordingly you can finish it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364099/reload-sharedpreferences-on-resume-or-how-to-refresh-reload-activity